# Why does a show() on a pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame cause Zeppelin to hang?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have a simple paragraph of Python code in Apache Zeppelin 0.10.0:

```
%livy.pyspark3
handMadeFrame = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, "foo"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        (2, "bar"),
    ],
    ["id", "label"]  # add your column names here
)

print(type(handMadeFrame))
handMadeFrame.printSchema()
```

It prints:

```
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- label: string (nullable = true)
```

All good so far.  If I add either:

```
handMadeFrame.take(2)
```

or

```
handMadeFrame.show()
```

Zeppelin hangs.  Why?  How can I debug this?